# Iphone 4 works with radio, I phone 5 doesnt

Tags: ios, audio

I have a Pioneer T1809 car stereo with aux adapter for Ipod/phone. It will work with my friends Iphone 4 but will only charge my Iphone 5.. No music.. It doesnt recognize it as being hooked up. Will I need to get a new cable or a new adapter for the existing cable. I had to use an adapter to hook it up to the 5 obviously, do I have the wrong one or do I need an entirely new cable.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that most adapters will charge the 5 but not play music unless it has the 3.5mm plug.  People then complain that doesn't work well unless you take the case off.  Read the reviews of these adapters.  It looks like you and I may have to get a bluetooth adapter for our t1809s.  Look up Coolstream Duo or go [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GHUHMUS).  We will have an opportunity to hide the bluetooth behind the console using [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005UHDCYY).